# Facing Issue: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/JcaJceHelper when using the updated BC jar

Tags: java, hadoop, encryption, public-key-encryption, password-encryption

I was using `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-150.jar` jar in my project, now due to some issues I have to update the BC jar to `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.64.jar`.

But When we added updated jar I  faced the issue

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/JcaJceHelper
```

I have tried every solution that I found on google but not succeeded. I have tried to find out the dependencies but did not get any helpful solution. I further investigated and found that the class `JcaJceHelper` exits under `util` folder of updated jar but don't know how to fix the issue.

Any help will be appreciated